# dynamically populating dropdown in form array in Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

In my reactive form array in Angular 13, I have a 3 radio buttons and when select any of the radio buttons, I need to populate a dropdown dynamically. Can someone help me on this ? below is the html from Angular template

```
          <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let renewalStatus of renewalStatusList">

            <input class="form-check" type="radio" value={{renewalStatus}} formControlName="status" (change)="unCheckHeader(renewalStatus,order)">

          </div>
```

```
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm fontSize7Rem" formControlName="actionReason">

          <option [ngValue]=0 selected>Select Reason</option>

          <option *ngFor="let actionReason of actionReasons" [ngValue]="actionReason.key">

            {{actionReason.value}}

          </option>

        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can push `actionReasons` list directly from the function `unCheckHeader`. But to be clearly can you provide for code in part of **.ts** file.